# How to call iOS native iOS JS on Flutter web

Tags: flutter

eg. in the h5 call iOS native iOS JS i wiil do this

```
window.webkit.messageHandlers.name.postMessage(params)
```

but on the flutter web

I don't know how to do it

please help me thanks

I'm trying to do this

```
js.context.callMethod("name", [
  jsonEncode({"id": 1001})
]);
```

But it didn't work